# Binding a Distinction basedon Actual Width to Visibility

Tags: wpf, binding, visibility

Is it possible to bind an `ActualWidth` or `Width` property of a Control to the `Visibility` of another Control with a distinction about value (like <200)? In my Opinion it is only possible with a converter because a `DataTrigger` can not work with `>` or `<`.

So I tried it with a Converter but it didn't work. I'm not sure which `BindingMode` is necessary and which kind of converter I need for such a solution.

The xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Height="36" Width="220" Maximum="500"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="mover"  Height="12" Stroke="Black" Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFFF9E0E" Height="34" Width="112" Visibility="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource umkehr}, ElementName=rectangle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and the idea for the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (value != null) {
       var val = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        if (val > 100)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Are you trying to change the Visibility based on another controls width?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to bind on the current element's ActualWidth?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely not working because you are binding your Rectangle's `Visibility` to the same rectangle's `ActualWidth`, and an invisible rectangle will always have a width of 0, so will never be visible.

Here's some examples. One binds to the other rectangle's `ActualWidth`, and the other binds to your Slider's `Value`

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" 
           Visibility="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mover, 
               Converter={StaticResource umkehr}}"/>
```

or

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" 
           Visibility="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider, 
               Converter={StaticResource umkehr}}"/>
```

And as far as I know, there's no easy way of basing a value off of  if something is greater than or less than a value. Coverters are your best option.

Comment: I'm guessing his intent is to bind to the other control but didn't type it correctly, because what is the point of making a 0 width control hidden? It's already not visible!

Answer (score 1):

`ActualWidth` is a readonly property exposed by FrameworkElement class -

```
public double ActualWidth { get; }
```

It is get only property hence you can't set it to other value from code. You can bind to Width of your control instead to make it work.

**EDIT**

This works for me, may be this is what you want -

**Converter**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is double)
    {
       return ((double)value > 100) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
   <Slider x:Name="slider" Height="36" Width="220" Maximum="500"/>
   <Rectangle x:Name="mover"  Height="12" Stroke="Black" Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFFF9E0E" Height="34" Width="112" Visibility="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ElementName=mover, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I was going to state that, but after rereading the question I think he's looking for (actualwidth > somevalue) -> Visible;

Comment: In your xaml, i guess by mistake you bind rectangle "rectangle" visibility to ActualWidth of itself(112) instead of binding to the ActualWidth of rectangle "mover".. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to change the [`Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.95).aspx) of a control based on the [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) of another control, you'll either need to use a [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) or you're own type of [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx) (inherit from [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) or [`BindingBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.aspx)).

Converter Option:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Double), typeof(Visibility))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(Double?), typeof(Visibility))]
public class MinimumLengthToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Double MinLength { get; set; }

    public override Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((value == null) || !(value is Double))
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        return (((Double)value) > MinLength) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public override Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

MarkupExtension Option:

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/09/30/comparabledatatrigger.aspx) blog post to get a better feel for how to implement this...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have the value in a **parameter**, so you can re-use the converter if you need to:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double cutoff = 0.0;

            if(parameter is double)
            {
                cutoff = (double)parameter;
            }

            if (parameter is string)
            {
                Double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out cutoff); 
            }

            if (value is double)
            {
                return ((double)value > cutoff) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

And the XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Height="36" Width="220" Maximum="500"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="mover"  Height="12" Stroke="Black" Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
     <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFFF9E0E" Height="34" Width="112" 
                Visibility="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ActualWidthToVisibilityConverter},                                                                                               
                ElementName=mover, Mode=OneWay, ConverterParameter=100}"/>
</StackPanel>
```